# Restangular - Client_credentials grant type not supported?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, restangular

Code below won't work. Grant type is "client_credentials". It returns null response with status -1. API is okay. Both requests work fine on postman

```
function authentication(user) {
            return Restangular
                .all('token')
                .post('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + APPLICATION.clientId + '&client_secret=' + 'XYZ',
                undefined, { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        }
```

Code below works perfectly with "password" grant type.

```
function authentication(user) {
            return Restangular
                .all('token')
                .post('grant_type=password&username=' + user.username + '&password=' + user.password + '&client_id=' + APPLICATION.clientId,
                undefined, { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the same `client_id` to make those calls. The 2nd working example shows that the Client is a so-called "public client" since it identifies itself without authentication. Your first example requires a confidential client since the Client needs to authenticate itself in a `client_credentials` flow. The two cannot be mixed so it looks like your Client is registered as a public client at the Authorization Server so by definition it cannot use a client credentials grant type.